# Open Existing Project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I tried to Open Excising Project in Eclipse. It shows error in project, But it runs well without any other in other system. But, when i opened the same in eclipse like `File-->Import-->select General--> Excising Project in Workspace-->Select Root Directory -->here`

I selected my project folder, after that i can able to import Project fully,every thing imported. But it shows error, Don't know what is that error, help me to fix this.. thanks in advance

Comment: You need to give us a clue, what kind of error u got... Please elaborate a bit so we can help you... For example what error message you got?

Comment: in your eclipse open the problems tab and check the error showing there. to open problem tab window->show view-> problem.

Comment: After viewed Problem tab, I saw that its version problem.. thank u all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also change Compiler level `Right click -> Propertis -> Java Compiler` or maybe, some **library** was **not imported** to this project. Is a lot of possibilities, give us a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Eclipse menu -> Project -> Clean..` can help error(s) to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the framework downloaded according to  that specific project's details,probably that is wot's causing this,,,Try checking if there's a build target specified in the Project properties.